# How to specify source branch name as the target folder in VSTS copy file task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to specify the target folder my packages as `c:\{mybranchname}\package`.

[image]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{Build.SourceBranchName}` isn't the correct syntax. If you review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch), you'll see that the correct syntax would be `$(Build.SourceBranchName)`.